# Gitlab Change Alertmanager Cluster Listen Adress

Tags: gitlab, prometheus-alertmanager

im currently having a problem while trying to change the gitlab alertmanager listen adress.
When i check the ports alertmanager is listening to, i get three results:

127.0.0.1:9093 tcp
0.0.0.0:9094 tcp
0.0.0.0:9094 udp

I can change the first one with alertmanager['listen_address'] = '127.0.0.1:9093' without a problem.
The other two are different. I want to set them to 127.0.0.1:9094 so that they arent reachable from outside anymore.

The only thing i found is that on this port is the cluster communication. I found two sources regarding that topic.
[Cluster Listen address vs Advertise address in AlertManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810535/cluster-listen-address-vs-advertise-address-in-alertmanager)
https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager#high-availability

The first one mentions to add a command section to the alertmanager config file. This didn't work for me. I got the following error: field command not found in type config.plain

In the second source they mention to add it as a startup argument. When i type gitlab-ctl restart alertmanager --cluster.listen-address="127.0.0.1:9094" nothing changes. It is still on 0.0.0.0:9094.

What else can i do? Has anyone tried to change this before?
Is it possible to only deactivate the cluster stuff?

Setup:

- Debian 12
- Selfmanaged Gitlab CE 16.3

Please let me know if some informations are missing.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I assume you are not using HA mod (since there is no much sense for cluster connection with only localhost allowed). Have you tried passing empty line into `--cluster.listen-address` to disable it as stated in linked README file?

Comment: Hi,
thanks four your reply. 
I tried both:
gitlab-ctl restart alertmanager --cluster.listen-address="127.0.0.1:9094"
gitlab-ctl restart alertmanager --cluster.listen-address
nothing worked
Is there an other way to deactivate the cluster feature as i dont want any proccesses listening on 0.0.0.0 which i don't need.

Comment: And have you tried `gitlab-ctl restart alertmanager --cluster.listen-address=""`?